# Deslizar para eliminar con firebase (CardView)

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, cardview

les contare mi problema, tengo una aplicación de notas en la cual implemente la opción de que al deslizar a la derecha se elimine la nota, el problema es que la nota no se elimina de la base de datos (FireBase) y al deslizar la nota a la derecha y eliminarla se queda un espacio vacío como el que se muestra en la siguiente foto:

[image: Al deslizar para eliminar nota se queda un espacio vacío]

Aquí les dejo el código entero de mi MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener {

private FirebaseAuth fAuth;
private RecyclerView mNotesList;

private String noteID;
private boolean isExist;


private DatabaseReference fNotesDatabase;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Guardamos el valor de Modo Noche
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SettingActivity.APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int theme = sharedPreferences.getInt(SettingActivity.THEME_Key, R.style.AppTheme);
    setTheme(theme);


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    // Obtenemos el ID de las notas
    try {
        noteID = getIntent().getStringExtra("noteId");

        //Toast.makeText(this, noteID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        isExist = !noteID.trim().equals("");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Recojemos los datos de las notas junto con su usuario
    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fNotesDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notes").child(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

    FloatingActionButton btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);


    DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notes");
    myRef.keepSynced(true);

    mNotesList = findViewById(R.id.notes_list);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    mNotesList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mNotesList.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    mNotesList.addItemDecoration(new GirdSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));


    // Si el usurio no se encuentra
    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        fNotesDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notes").child(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        loadData();
        setupNavigation(savedInstanceState, toolbar);
    }


    updateUI();
}


// Menu de la izquierda
private void setupNavigation(Bundle savedInstanceState, Toolbar toolbar) {

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();


    String lEmail = user.getEmail();


    List<IDrawerItem> iDrawerItems = new ArrayList<>();

    iDrawerItems.add(new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.notas).withIcon(R.drawable.icon_note));

    List<IDrawerItem> stockItems = new ArrayList<>();

    stockItems.add(new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.ajustes).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_settings_white_24dp));
    stockItems.add(new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.ayuda).withIcon(R.drawable.ic_help_outline_black_24dp));

    AccountHeader header = new AccountHeaderBuilder().withActivity(this)
            .addProfiles(new ProfileDrawerItem()
                    .withIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .withEmail(lEmail))
            .withTextColorRes(R.color.colorThreeText)
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .withSelectionListEnabledForSingleProfile(false)
            .build();

    new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .withDrawerItems(iDrawerItems)
            .withStickyDrawerItems(stockItems)
            .withAccountHeader(header)
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(this)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}

// Carga todos los datos
private void loadData() {

    Query query = fNotesDatabase.orderByValue();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<NoteModel> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<NoteModel>()
                    .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<NoteModel>() {
                        @NonNull
                        @Override
                        public NoteModel parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            return new NoteModel(snapshot.child("titulo").getValue().toString(),
                                    snapshot.child("content").getValue().toString(),
                                    snapshot.child("timestamp").getValue().toString());
                        }
                    })
                    .build();

    final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NoteModel, NoteViewHolder>(options) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.single_note_layout, parent, false);
            return new NoteViewHolder(view);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NoteViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull NoteModel model) {
            final String noteId = getRef(position).getKey();

            fNotesDatabase.child(noteId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("titulo") && dataSnapshot.hasChild("timestamp") && dataSnapshot.hasChild("content")) {
                        String title = dataSnapshot.child("titulo").getValue().toString();
                        String content = dataSnapshot.child("content").getValue().toString();
                        String timestamp = dataSnapshot.child("timestamp").getValue().toString();

                        holder.setNoteTitle(title);
                        holder.setNoteContent(content);
                        //holder.setNoteTime(timestamp);
                        if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage() != "en") {
                            holder.setNoteTime(GetTimeAgoSpanish.getTimeAgoSpanish(Long.parseLong(timestamp), getApplicationContext()));

                        } else {
                            holder.setNoteTime(GetTimeAgo.getTimeAgo(Long.parseLong(timestamp), getApplicationContext()));
                        }

                        if (title.isEmpty()) {
                            holder.textTitle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            holder.textTitle.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0f));
                        }


                        holder.noteCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewNoteActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("noteId", noteId);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
    };
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    mNotesList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    // Creamos un nuevo ItemTouchHelper para el swipe to delete
    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mNotesList);

}

private void updateUI() {

    if (fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        Log.i("MainActivity", "fAuth != null");
    } else {
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
        startActivity(startIntent);
        finish();
        Log.i("MainActivity", "fAuth == null");
    }

}

// Convierte el formato en que se creo la nota
private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    Resources r = getResources();
    return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
}

// Acciones al apretar el boton de +
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewNoteActivity.class);
    startActivity(newIntent);
}

// Acciones al apretar los botones del menu
@Override
public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
    switch (position) {
        case -1:
            Intent settingIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingActivity.class);
            startActivity(settingIntent);
            return false;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

// Obtenemos los botones del ToolBar
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mai_menu_activity, menu);
    return true;
}

// Acciones de los botones del ToolBar
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            Intent settingIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(settingIntent);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

// Swipe to Delete

ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        if (isExist) {
            DeleteNote();
        }
    }
};

public void DeleteNote() {
    fNotesDatabase.child(noteID).removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.nota_eliminada, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                noteID = "no";
                finish();
            } else {
                Log.e("MainActivity", task.getException().toString());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Espero se logre entender mi código y me puedan a ayudar a resolver el problema de no poder eliminar la nota de la base de datos, ya que vi muchos códigos implementando esto y busque soluciones pero ninguna me ayudo a que funcione como yo quiero mi código, no se si lo este implementando mal o este poniendo el código en algún lugar que no corresponde espero me puedan guiar para que funcione mi código de deslizar para eliminar.

Comment: Se supone que cuando introduces una nota en la base de datos, la identificas con un identificador (`noteID`, entiendo), así que cuando quieres eliminar una, le pasas ese `noteID` para identificar la nota que quieres borrar en la base de datos. En tu código no entiendo lo que estás haciendo con la variable `noteID`. ¿Cómo seleccionas la nota que quieres borrar cuando la deslizas?

Comment: `// Obtenemos el ID de las notas
    try {
        noteID = getIntent().getStringExtra("noteId");

        //Toast.makeText(this, noteID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        isExist = !noteID.trim().equals("");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`. con ese código debería obtener el id de las notas pero me acabo de dar cuenta que no obtiene el id de las notas con ese código, tendré que buscar como obtener el id de las notas de otra forma

Comment: Ya pude arreglarlo gracias a que tu comentario me hizo dar cuenta que no obtenía el id de mis notas

Comment: Entiendo que cada nota tendrá un `id` único que la identifica en la base de datos. Cuando llamas a `removeValue`, sobre un `child`, ese `child` es una nota concreta identificada con el `noteID`, por eso no se entendía que obtuvieras el `noteID` en el `onCreate`. ¿De qué nota es ese `noteID`? Cuando seleccionas la nota que vas a borrar, obtienes el `id` de esa nota y entonces haces el `child(noteID).removeValue()`. Suerte!